# bulk update with Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, bulk

how can I do bulk update with the Mongoid?

Specifically, copy one existing field to another of the same document.

```
Product.collection.command("db.products.find(
    {gender : { $ne : null } }
  ).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.archive_gender = doc.gender;
    doc.gender = null;
    db.products.save(doc);
  })"
)
```

Cheers,
Khoa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoid Batch Update/Upsert Alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550690/mongoid-batch-update-upsert-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

ok, so we're able to $eval any javascript, but let me know of better solutions. This is how I was able to achieve bulk update in MongoDB from one field with another.

```
db = Mongoid::Config::master
db.command({"$eval" => <<-ENDJS})
  db.products.find({
    gender:{ $ne: null }
  }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.archive_gender = doc.gender;
    doc.gender = null;
    db.products.save(doc);
  })
ENDJS
```

Cheers,
Khoa.