# Mongoid Batch Update/Upsert Alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, batch-processing

I know that Mongoid v3+ supports batch inserts via `Model.collection.insert()`. However, I don't think it supports batch updates where the attributes differ for each record (so I don't think `update_all` would work either). Is there a way to do batch update/upsert instead of a single-record lookup & update?

Here's a simplified example in which I have 2 models:

```
class Product
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end

class List
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

When a new `Product` is created, I associate it with one or more `Lists`. However, I also need to update the `Product` attributes daily without losing the `List` reference info (I'm ok that validation on `Product` doesn't run).

One way, without using batch, is to call `find_or_initialize_by` on `Product` and update the attributes. But doing so for 10K-1M+ records is very time consuming.

Another way, which uses batch insert, is to do `Product.delete_all` and then `Product.collection.insert(...)`, but that creates new `product_ids` and the relationship with `List` is no longer maintained.

Is there a way to do batch update or upsert in this example?

Comment: Can you share your document schema. I don't use the mongoid embedded documents much, but I may be able to help you with what you are trying to achieve using moped (the mongoid driver) if I have a fair idea about what your documents look like, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess this doesn't have to be an embedded documents specific question. If the relations were `has_many/belongs_to`, would a solution using moped exist?

Comment: If you could edit your question and let me know the actual schema (what the documents look like), and what you are trying to achieve in terms of data, then I might be able to help. Relations (has_many/belongs_to) are an abstraction built by mongoid, and not inherent to mongo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 supports the `update` command, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/

`Mongoid.default_session` gives you corresponding access to the `command` method at the MongoDB database level.
The following example shows how to construct and issue a bulk update command that should answer your question.
The output shows the 10 lists,
comparison of individual versus bulk-update run times,
a dump of the Product collection showing updated stock counts,
and the structure of the bulk update command.
Even in this simple demo, there is significant performance improvement with bulk updates versus individual updates.

The Ruby 'mongo' 1.x driver supports a fluent API for bulk writes,
this will also be supported by the new Ruby 'mongo' 2.0 driver that will eventually find its way into Mongoid.
Mongoid v3+ currently uses the Moped driver which does not have a fluent API for bulk write.
But as demonstrated here,
it is fairly straightforward to construct and directly issue a bulk write (bulk update) command
in Mongoid/Moped via the Session#command method.

Hope that this helps.

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :stock, type: Integer, default: 0
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists, index: true
end
```

app/models/list.rb

```
class List
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

test/unit/product_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'benchmark'
require 'pp'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @session = Mongoid.default_session
    @session.drop
  end
  test '0. mongoid version' do
    puts "\nMongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  def individual_updates(list_ids, repetitions)
    repetitions.times do
      list_ids.each_with_index do |list_id, index|
        Product.where(:list_ids => list_id).update_all({'$inc' => {'stock' => index}})
      end
    end
  end
  def bulk_command(list_ids, repetitions)
    updates = []
    repetitions.times do
      list_ids.each_with_index do |list_id, index|
        updates << {'q' => {'list_ids' => list_id}, 'u' => {'$inc' => {'stock' => index}}, 'multi' => true}
      end
    end
    { update: Product.collection_name.to_s, updates: updates, ordered: false }
  end
  def bulk_updates(list_ids, repetitions)
    @session.command(bulk_command(list_ids, repetitions))
  end
  test 'x' do
    puts
    [
      ['ASUS MeMO Pad FHD 10', ['ASUS', 'tablet', 'Android']],
      ['Apple iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular 128GB - Silver', ['Apple', 'tablet', 'iOS']],
      ['Apple iPad mini with Retina display Wi-Fi + Cellular 128GB - Silver', ['Apple', 'tablet', 'iOS']],
      ['Apple iPhone 5c 32GB Green', ['Apple', 'phone', 'iOS']],
      ['Apple iPhone 5s 64GB Space Gray', ['Apple', 'phone', 'iOS']],
      ['LG G Pad 8.3 Tablet', ['LG', 'tablet', 'Android']],
      ['LG Google Nexus 5 White', ['LG', 'phone', 'Android']],
      ['Microsoft Surface 7ZR-00001', ['Microsoft', 'tablet', 'Windows 8 RT']],
      ['Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500', ['Samsung', 'phone', 'Android']],
      ['Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4', ['Samsung', 'tablet', 'Android']]
    ] .each do |product_name, list_names|
      product = Product.create(name: product_name)
      list_names.each do |list_name|
        list = List.where(name: list_name).first_or_create
        list.products << product
      end
    end
    list_names = List.all.to_a.collect(&:name).sort.uniq
    p list_names
    list_ids = list_names.collect{|list_name| List.where(name: list_name).first.id}
    assert(list_ids.count > 0)

    Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
      x.report('individual updates') { individual_updates(list_ids, 100) }
      x.report('bulk updates') { bulk_updates(list_ids, 100) }
    end

    pp Product.all.to_a

    db_command = bulk_command(list_ids, 1)
    assert(db_command[:updates].size > 0)
    pp db_command
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/2] ProductTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.6
Moped::VERSION:1.5.2
[2/2] ProductTest#test_x
["ASUS", "Android", "Apple", "LG", "Microsoft", "Samsung", "Windows 8 RT", "iOS", "phone", "tablet"]
                           user     system      total        real
individual updates     0.420000   0.070000   0.490000 (  0.489579)
bulk updates           0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.180926)
[#<Product _id: 5408b72b7f11bad1ca000001, name: "ASUS MeMO Pad FHD 10", stock: 2000, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000002", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca000005, name: "Apple iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular 128GB - Silver", stock: 3600, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000006", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000007"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca000008, name: "Apple iPad mini with Retina display Wi-Fi + Cellular 128GB - Silver", stock: 3600, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000006", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000007"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca000009, name: "Apple iPhone 5c 32GB Green", stock: 3400, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000006", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000a", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000007"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000b, name: "Apple iPhone 5s 64GB Space Gray", stock: 3400, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000006", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000a", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000007"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000c, name: "LG G Pad 8.3 Tablet", stock: 2600, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000d", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000e, name: "LG Google Nexus 5 White", stock: 2400, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000d", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000a", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000f, name: "Microsoft Surface 7ZR-00001", stock: 3800, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000010", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000011"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca000012, name: "Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500", stock: 2800, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000013", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000a", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"]>,
 #<Product _id: 5408b72c7f11bad1ca000014, name: "Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4", stock: 3000, list_ids: ["5408b72c7f11bad1ca000013", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003", "5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"]>]
{:update=>"products",
 :updates=>
  [{"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000002"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>0}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000004"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>1}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000006"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>2}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000d"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>3}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000010"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>4}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000013"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>5}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000011"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>6}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000007"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>7}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca00000a"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>8}},
    "multi"=>true},
   {"q"=>{"list_ids"=>"5408b72c7f11bad1ca000003"},
    "u"=>{"$inc"=>{"stock"=>9}},
    "multi"=>true}],
 :ordered=>false}
Finished tests in 1.334821s, 1.4983 tests/s, 1.4983 assertions/s.
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Please note that BSON::ObjectId objects return the string on inspection, but that values are really instances of BSON::ObjectID and not String.

Comment: Thank you Gary, let me try that and get back.

Comment: There is no batch `upsert` command right? I'm thinking about simulating batch `upsert` via this process, any thoughts? Process: 1. Use `find_or_initialize_by` to create the models in memory, 2. Use batch update to save.

Comment: Bulk `upsert` is incorporated into the bulk `update` command.  The `upsert` sub-field is a boolean at the same level as the `q` field, please see the documentation for `upsert` on the referenced page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/

Comment: Can the 'u' part of the command leverage Mongoid's `as_document` instead of setting every attribute of a model?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I tried this: `products.each do |product|
 updates << {'q' => {'external_id' => product.external_id}, 'u' => product.as_document, 'multi' => false, 'upsert' => true}
 end`  However, this causes problems during update since the `_id` of the document already exists and can't be changed. Is there a way to use as_document but excluding `_id` or do I need to create the hash manually?

Comment: Just delete `_id` from the hash returned from `as_document`, e.g., `def without_id(h); h.delete('_id'); h; end` with usage `'u' => without_id(product.as_document)`

Comment: Thanks, btw, the performance gains so far has been really impressive. One quick questions, what's the difference between MongoDB's `db.collection.update()` and `command.update`?

Comment: `db.collection.update()` is the mongo shell user interface method to do an update with MongoDB (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and this maps to the "new" update command with a 2.6 server which supports bulk updates (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/) or the "old" OP_UPDATE wire protocol operation with a 2.4 or older server which is single request only (http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/).

Comment: Hi Gary, is there a way to query using the `_id` of the document? I have something like this: `        updates << {'q' => {'_id' => 'xxx'},
                    'u' =>  {'$set' => {'sequence' => 3}},
                    'multi' => false,
                    'upsert' => false}` where `xxx` is the document _id. However, that doesn't seem to work in finding the document.

Comment: Dean, what is the type of your `_id`'s?  The default/generated type is `BSON::ObjectId`, so a String won't match, even if it is the string printed by inspecting the _id of type BSON::ObjectId. If you have code that works with individual update operations, then you should be able to easily make the equivalent bulk operations, using very similar select/query doc-hashes for both.

Comment: _id is ObjectId. I'm using Mongoid so it's usually Model.find('xxxx'). How do I do a select query not using Mongoid for _id?

Comment: For the selector/query, please try {'_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string('xxx')} and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Gary, that worked wonders! I just made one minor change to reference Moped: `{'_id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string('xxx')}`

Comment: Hi Gary, I encountered another situation and would be interested in your guidance. For command.update, does it override all fields in a record even if it's not specified in the update? For example, the record has an attributed `featured = true`, but after the bulk update, it's set to `featured = false`, the default value of the model, even though it's removed from the `u` fields. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using the `product.as_document` function described above, and removing the `featured` attribute. Resulting in `"{"q"=>{"match_id"=>"23423423424"}, "u"=>{"status"=>"active"}, "multi"=>false, "upsert"=>true}"`. I'm not using the `$set` method described in the MongoDB doc. Should I use that? If so, how does that work with `as_document`?

Comment: If your <update> document does not contain update modifiers like `$set`, i.e., it contains only `field:value` expressions, then it is a (full) replacement as documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Probably Gary's answer worked. But I found in mongoid 5.x and 6.x which uses the standard mongodb ruby driver, it is possible to do `Model.mongo_client.bulk_write([op1, op2, ...], options)`. See

- https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/
- https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/2.4.0/Mongo/Collection.html#bulk_write-instance_method

Needed both documents to make sense of constructing the call. e.g

```
  update = TestCase.collection.bulk_write(
    [
      replace_one: {
        filter: {},
        update: {},
        upsert: true
      },
      update_one: { ... },
      ...
    ],
    ordered: false
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, was trying the same thing with camelized operators `updateOne` until you made me realize the driver had snake-cased them

Comment: This answer works, also, in the filter, you must use the `'a.b.c' => 1` notation rather than `{a: {b: {c: 1}}}`

Comment: @Shiyason, I think this difference is not specific for this operation but depends on what yo uare trying to achieve when using the standard ruby driver.