# How to bulk update/upsert with mongoid/mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a database with millions of `Order`documents. I batch insert them with the following method:

```
Order.collection.insert([
                         {:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfb0000'), :status=>"open", :name=> "Benny"},
                         {:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfc0000'), :status=>"open", :name=> "Allan"}
                        ])
```

I regularly need to update the `status` attribute on the orders. It would be way to inefficient to update them individually with the `update_attribute` method.

**How do I bulk update multiple MongoDB documents?**

The desired solution can best be described with the below "fictional" code:

```
# IMPORTANT: The exemplified upsert method does not exist

Order.collection.upsert([
                         {:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfb0000'), :status=>"closed"},
                         {:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfc0000'), :status=>"some_other_status"}
                        ])
```

Fyi, there might be a similar question/answer [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550690/mongoid-batch-update-upsert-alternative), but in all honesty I don't follow the answer.

Comment: The answer in the linked question gives a long example but the key line for you to understand (and work backwards from) is this: "{ update: Product.collection_name.to_s, updates: updates, ordered: false }"   It's the update command that takes multiple update directives.   "updates" argument is a list of updates to be made - look backwards through the code to see how that batch of updates was built.

Comment: Hi @AsyaKamsky, could you put it in as a shorter and more concise answer to this question? I only have 2 more days to award the bounty to an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoid Batch Update/Upsert Alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550690/mongoid-batch-update-upsert-alternative)

Answer (score 6):

The best answer in the referenced question can be simplified to

```
id_status = [['5471944843687229cdfb0000','closed'], ...] 

bulk_order = id_status.map do |id, status| # Using array destructuration
  { update_one:
    {
      filter: { _id: id },
      update: { :'$set' => {
        status: status,
      }}
    }
  }
end
YourCollection.collection.bulk_write(bulk_order)
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you'll need to filter `Orders` for only those matching ids of `orders_to_update`.
You filter them with the [any_in Criteria method](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in). Then update all of them in bulk with [update_all](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html).

Like so:

```
orders_to_update = [BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfb0000'), BSON::ObjectId('5471944843687229cdfc0000')]

Order.any_in(id: orders_to_update).update_all(status: "closed")
```

Comment: @Anzeo: Basically, we filter Orders for only those matching ids of "orders_to_update" with `any_in` Criteria method (http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in) and update all of them in bulk with `update_all` (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Though all documents in my example should be updated with the same value (`closed`) my "fictional" example asks for a real life solution where I can specify what is to be updated on each document. So e.g. one of the documents could be updated with the value `closed` while the other one could be updated with `refunded`.

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen - would it be feasible to handle those updates individually? In other words, bulk update everything that should be changed to `closed` and then bulk update everything that should be changed to `refunded`. If not, then how do you determine what the status of each document should be? I'm hoping this info can inform how to revise this answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your question. But in cases where the updated field is e.g. a relation (so all values are unikke) the would not save time. The only possibility as far as I see it is to be able to define an array of MongoDB ID's together with field names and field values.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here are **updates**. Updates are slow because it needs to read, replace and change a document.

I've been blocked with in the same problem for many days. I didn't find any solution in stackoverflow nor in any other websites. Therefore, I wrote my own solution. Maybe you will find that it's not very "clean", but it works with excellent time results.

**The solution consists in destroy an create again this document**. Destroy is very fast, and create new documents using the bulk execution "collection.insert" is super fast.

```
def get_orders(*params)
   Order.where(# some conditions).asc(:id)
end

namespace :my_collection_repairer do
desc ""

  task update: :environment do
    all_orders = get_orders(# some conditions)
    while all_orders.count > 0
      num_docs = all_orders.count
      group_size = 10000
      num_groups = (Float(num_docs) / group_size).ceil
      puts "#{num_docs} documents found. #{num_groups} groups calculated."

      1.upto(num_groups) do |group|
        updated_order_list = []
        order_group = all_orders.page(group).per(group_size)
        puts "group #{group}"

        order_group.each do |order|
          updated_order = update_order(order) # this represents your custom update method
          updated_order_list << updated_order.as_document
          order.destroy
        end

        Order.collection.insert(updated_order_list)
        puts "Group #{group} updated."
      end
      all_orders = get_orders(# some conditions)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Sets the upsert option to true for an update or a replacement operation and has the following **syntax**:

```
 bulk.find( { status: "closed" } ).update( { $set: { status: "some_other_status" } } );
 bulk.execute();
```

Adds a multi update operation to a bulk operations list. The method updates specific fields in existing documents.

Use the **Bulk.find()** method to specify the condition that determines which documents to update. The **Bulk.find.update()** method updates all matching documents. To specify a single document update, see **Bulk.find.updateOne()**.

```
 var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
 bulk.find( { status: "closed" } ).upsert().update(
{
 $set: { status: "some_other_status"}
}
);
bulk.execute();
```

**Note**:

To specify upsert: true for this operation, use **Bulk.find.upsert()**. With **Bulk.find.upsert()**, if no documents match the **Bulk.find()** query condition, the update operation inserts only a single document.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @SUNDARRAJANK. But could you maybe edit or add the example so it uses example values corresponding to the ones in the question? I'm having a hard time following what `Bulk`, etc. represents.

Comment: Also, even though all documents in my example should be updated with the same value (`closed`) my "fictional" example asks for a real life solution where I can specify what is to be updated on each document. So e.g. one of the documents could be updated with the value `closed` while the other one could be updated with `refunded`.

Comment: var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

Comment: Hi again @SUNDARRAJANK. Sorry, but I'm not following the last comment.

Comment: bulk is mongo db's inbuilt UnorderedBulk data which stores a cursor for usage of operations like insert,delete, update,remove  refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/

Comment: I would love to understand this answer, but I don't. Can't you edit the answer so it uses the same variables/values as in the question? I don't understand MongoDB syntax. And the question is in Ruby context, so I need the answer to be as well.

Comment: He has mentioned a mongoDB query, ruby on rails doesn't even support bulk inserts as far as I am concerned.